# What's the benefits of writing JavaScript code using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

While reading Kotlin to JavaScript tutorial, I'm just wondered what's the benefits of writing JavaScript code using Kotlin?

Beside,
there are already great tools for Javascript developing, like package-manager, Webpack, Gulp...

Comment: I don't think there are any benefits of writing JavaScript using Kotlin if you familiar with Node.js stack. TypeScript provides type-safe like Kotlin.

Comment: The reason is that those tools are crap compared to Java tools like Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is similar to using javascript for server and client. A common language with shared code.

Kotlin can be used for server and client, and aspects of code can be shared. Can use JVM for back-end, and JS tools/frameworks for front-end.

I'm not necessarily recommending this approach, but can see value in it. If you already know Kotlin, it means you don't have to learn JS.

Kotlin is also officially supported for creating Android apps, and Jetbrains are in the process of allowing for development of iOS apps in Kotlin.

So, can use one language across all platforms.